# Npm make error on polymer dependency compile

Tags: npm, polymer, browser-sync

```
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/nodejs-binary-4.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
```

I have been trying to get my first ever polymer starter app working but can't get 'npm install' to work, apparently because of a well documented node-gyp(?) compile error which prevents browser-sync and other dependencies from installing with npm. But I find no (applicable) solution or workarounds, just others posting variations of the same problem.

I believe I have exhausted every googled resource and npm workaround that I can find or try.

- This is a yeoman install of polymer project 'yo polymer' per the advise of the top polymer gurus and polymer site
- on ubuntu desktop 14.04 updated to latest
- with node v4.0.0 with npm v2.14.2
- running as a vagrant vm
- make, gcc, m4, libtool, build-essential, autoconf, python installed and updated and triple checked as OK
- many other npm dependencies have used make successfully, or so it appears
- node-gyp installs fine by itself if -g or if --no-bin-links
- gyp installs fine by itself if -g or if --no-bin-links
- I can replicate exact error message by 'npm install browser-sync'
- runs same in root or my user

If I remove this dependency, there are other dependencies that get the exact same error on installing.

Comment: fails same way in centos, but centos does seem to provide slightly better information about the failure(?)

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question:

- revert to node 0.11.16
- run 'npm install --no-bin-links', not 'npm install'

Reason: Apparently nan migrated from 1 to 2, and broke the build for A LOT of things that consume it as source code, if using node 0.12 or 4.0. See https://github.com/nodejs/nan/issues/451

Editorial comment:
This is my first foray into js. Js programmers have too much patience with their platform - my2c. It seems ludicrous that I'm the one that posted the answer to this question, when I'm basically an idiot level at node.